# how to get the Y value on the curve using flot js

Tags: javascript, flot

Using the flot js graphing library, you can get the (x,y) position of the mouse. Given a curve represented by plot values, how can you get the interpolated Y value on the curve for the given mouse position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [crosshair/tracking demo](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/tracking.html) on their pages. It has an `updateLegend` method which simply takes the nearest x values at the crosshair line and does some linear interpolation.